# Normally distributed random variable df and $x^2$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm working on a simulation of an environment. I'm basing it on a paper that describes a mathematical model for the variables, one of them is described as:

> "Analyses of these data indicated that the
>    annual precipitation series can be well described
>    as a normally distributed random variable ($x^2$ = 1.0,
>    5 df), with a mean and variance of 41.81 cm and
>    11.20 cm, respectively"

So I'm trying to model it with python using numpy which includes a method *numpy.random.normal* which randomly samples from a gaussian distribution and takes as parameters the center and standard deviation of the distribution. I understand that this parameters are the mean and the square root of the variance provided in the description but I can't figure out the meaning of the *"($x^2$ = 1.0,
 5 df)"* part.

Could you help me understand those two concepts and how could I fit those into my simulation?

**Edit**: there's another variable described as:

> The random variable $k_n$ represents the fact that the specific result
>    of a particular decision is known only probabilistically. A symmetric density was assumed for $k_n$ using $D_n(X_n)$ as the mean, with probability 0.6.
>    Values 10% above and below the mean were allowed, each with probability 0.2.

I understood that the variable can only take the value $D_n(X_n)$ with probability 0.6 OR the same value +-10% but not the values between them. Am I correct?

Comment: Can you provide a link to said paper? Also, are you sure it is $x^2 = 1.0$ and not $\chi^2 = 1.0$? It seems reasonable to be about a Chi-square goodness-of-fit test with 5 degree of freedom, and the value of test statistic is 1.0 (note that the mean is 5).

Comment: The paper can be found here https://www.jstor.org/stable/1934697 and yeah maybe it can be chi, I can show an image of the original text if needed.